# AE.Net.Mail - Save a draft for an existing message

Tags: c#, .net, imap

How can I save a draft on an existing message?

The following code will execute but the draft is not saved in my Gmail:

```
Lazy<MailMessage>[] emails = imapClient.SearchMessages(searchCondition);
...
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e.Source == "AE.Net.Mail")
        throw new Exception("AE.Net.Mail error: " + e.Message, e);

    imapClient.SetFlags(Flags.Seen | Flags.Draft, emails[i].Value);
    imapClient.Expunge();
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        writer.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        emails[i].Value.Subject = e.Message;
        emails[i].Value.Save(writer);
    }
    imapClient.Expunge();
}
```

The mail is marked as seen, but not as draft. What am I doing wrong?